# FuncAnimation not updating with custom event_source in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some curves as they are being generated by another process (think training curves for a neural network as the neural network is being fitted, and *not* a posteriori). Ideally I would like the plot to be updated quite frequently, so the speed of the update is important.

I have a method working involving `ax.plot` but it is not super fast, thus limiting my ability to call it often. Looking into the doc, I was interested by `FuncAnimation` especially for the `blit` part (to gain some speed). In the code of [FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/animation.html#FuncAnimation), I noticed that it inherits from `TimedAnimation` which can take an `event_source` parameter. In fact I don't see anything in the code that makes it necessary for this `event_source` parameter to be time based. So I set myself to create my own "event_source like object". Every time my main code would have generated new data, it would trigger the update of my `EventSource`, drawing a new frame in the `FuncAnimation`.

I seem to have some of the logic in the code below (it does run and the prints are displayed in time). However the plot does not update live, it only update once, after the main call is done (this is done in Jupyter Notebook with `%matplotlib notebook`). 
Would you have any ideas why the plot does not update live?

```
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np # really just here to fake data 
from time import sleep
from typing import List, Callable

# %matplotlib notebook

def my_large_function(callbacks: List[Callable]):
    """
    This is assumed to be the main calling function, like some neural network training curves. We cannot 
    assume that each iteration is taking the same time (some may be considerably longer than others)

    callbacks are the functions to be called when some criteria is met
    """
    for i in range(50):
        if i%5==0:
            for c in callbacks:
                c()
            print("Update")
        else:
            print("Not update")

        sleep(0.5)

class MyVeryOwnEvent:
    """
    This is an implementation of the event_source interface used by FuncAnimation. 
    The function are actually copied from TimerBase
    https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/backend_bases.html#TimerBase
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.callbacks = list()

    def add_callback(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.callbacks.append((func, args, kwargs))
        return func

    def start(self):
        pass

    def stop(self):
        pass

    def _on_timer(self):
        print(f"In _on_timer {len(self.callbacks)}")
        for func, args, kwargs in self.callbacks:
            ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
            # docstring above explains why we use `if ret == 0` here,
            # instead of `if not ret`.
            # This will also catch `ret == False` as `False == 0`
            # but does not annoy the linters
            # https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values
            if ret == 0:
                self.callbacks.remove((func, args, kwargs))

        if len(self.callbacks) == 0:
            self.stop()


# This is the simple_anim example 
# https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/animation/simple_anim.html
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))


def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + i/10.0))  # update the data
    return line,


# Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
    return line,

# !!!!! tweaked here
event_source = MyVeryOwnEvent()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), init_func=init,
                              interval=25, blit=True,
                             event_source= event_source) # !!! and here 
plt.show()


my_large_function([event_source._on_timer]) 
# The above line you can see the prints, but the plot does not seem to refresh
```